# "as informative as" or "informative to such an extent"?

Tags: comparison

> Original: A. Make your contribution as informative as is required.
>
> My revision: B. Make your contribution  informative to such an extent is required.

I am wondering what is then subtle difference in meaning between the two?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sort of context *such* sets up a target **outcome**, an effect which is produced. Your revision, "Make your contribution informative to such an extent is required", is ungrammatical; the comparator *such* must be 'closed' with a finite *that* or *as* clause :

> Make your contribution informative to such an extent that your hearer is satisfied.
>   Make your contribution informative to such extent as will satisfy your hearer.

With one of those corrections the two constructions are semantically equivalent.

With a relative or reduced relative clause expressing a prior **constraint** rather than an effect or outcome, you should use *the* rather than *such*:

> Make your contribution informative to **the** extent [which is] required.

Note, however, that although this is an acceptable paraphrase of the original, and may help you understand what is expressed, it is unnecessarily and clumsily verbose; the simple *as ... as* construction is preferred.